# Can I purchase my own app without paying?

Tags: ios, app-store

I have just published my [first app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/solid-color/id1128751434?ls=1&mt=8) on the iOS App Store. It's a paid app (it's nothing special, but you have to start somewhere... :)

When I view it on the App Store it shows up like any other app including the price in the buy button.

Is it possible to "buy" it myself without paying?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This looks to me like it's more about how App Store works than a programming problem - I think it's off-topic here. Better take a look at our sister site [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible to buy the app without paying, unless you want to use one of your promotional codes, but I don't see the point in purchasing it, you have the entire Xcode project on your Mac. If you want to save this, you can simply copy it to another place on your hard drive (or wherever you want to store it) and save it for as long as you want

Comment: Thanks. I'll try the promotional code. I developed it myself (so I do have the source, etc), but it seems to expire on my phone so I thought buying it would be more permanent.

Comment: It shouldn't expire on your phone, unless you are internal testing with TestFlight, but you can hook you phone directly up to your computer and load it that way, and it should never expire.

Comment: @JordanWx, apps you install from Xcode **do** expire, and after a pretty short time. (90 days, if memory serves.)

Comment: I haven't run into that problem in my experience, but it could be possible I test my apps just far apart enough for this not to be a problem. You are right on your answer that promo codes refresh with every new version of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Open your project file in Xcode and then download it to your phone for free. I do not believe there is a way for you to download it from the App Store for free.

Answer (score 0):

Development promo codes expire after a fairly short time (90 days?)

If you want to test an App Store install, create a promo code and use that. It both exercises the actual App Store installation process, and installs an app that does not expire.

Promo codes aren't as limited as you might think. You get a new batch every time you update your app, and an app downloaded using a version 1.0 promo code can be updated indefinitely.

Comment: Feels to me like it's been far less than 90 days. In any case, I've done the promo code and installed the app and all working. Thx.